# Laravel/php upload not working

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-4

There are so many similar issues to this but none seemed to be exactly the same.

Here is some code I am using within a Facade

```
public function create($input, $index = false, $params = false)
{
    $file = Input::file($input);

    if ($file === null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if ($index !== false)
    {
        $file = $file[$index];
    }
    else
    {
        $file = reset($file);
    }

    if ($file === null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    $image              = new ImageModel;
    $image->mime        = $file->getClientMimeType();
    $image->extension   = $file->guessClientExtension();
    $image->filename    = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    if ($params !== false)
    {
        //there are parameters to add
    }
    $image->save();
    $image->hash = md5($image->id);

    $path = str_split($image->hash);
    $path = array_slice($path, 0, 5);

    $system_path = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);

    $fileName = substr($image->hash, 5);
    $path[] = $fileName;

    $image->path = implode('/', $path);
    $destination_path = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, [public_path(), 'images', $system_path, null]);

    if (self::_makePath($destination_path))
    {
        $file_path = implode('.', [$destination_path.$fileName, $image->extension]);
        $image->save();
        dd([
            $file->getRealPath(),
            file_exists($file->getRealPath()),
            file_exists($destination_path),
            $file_path,
            is_writable($destination_path),
            move_uploaded_file($file->getRealPath(), $file_path)
        ]);
        move_uploaded_file($file->getRealPath(), $file_path);
        //$file->move($destination_path, $fileName);

        $this->image = $image;

        return $this->image;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The objective of this function is to create a hash of the image id, then use that to create a directory path to the image, ensuring that the upload will always be unique.

This function was working fine using `$file->move` fairly recently in a homestead application (laravel 4.2 and not the latest version of homestead, also adjusted to an extent but none of the php/nginx values were changed) however without any adjustments to it for some time, it stopped working. I have tried changing the function to alternate ways to do the upload but nothing. All it says is that the file could not be upload for an unknown reason.

Using code above I have some tests there for if the file can be uploaded/ moved and it all checks out, even `move_uploaded_file` returns true, however no file is moved.

Comment: Without looking at the code too closely, have you checked the permissions of the target directory?

Comment: Yes, I was using `is_writable` to check using a dump.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue, although its a mistake on my part it is something hard to track down.

Basically the upload was running twice, It was working but because the latest image was the second one it made it seem like it wasn't. Using laravel it is hard to see this unless you see the 2 rows added to the database, but if you are not storing them in the database that option is gone.

The code running twice was the call to the Facade, so the above code does not list it.